# SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database on android X.0.X versions

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

i know there exists many posts regarding this issue but the issue i am facing goes like this..

The app works perfectly when run on 4.0,5.0,5.1,6 ets

> "SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not
>   open database"

if its run i 4.0.1,5.0.2 or 6.0.1 or to be in general X.0.X but works fine in X.1.X

can any one help me out with this issue

My crash logs proof:

```
USER_COMMENT=null
ANDROID_VERSION=6.0.1
APP_VERSION_NAME=0.0337
BRAND=google
PHONE_MODEL=Nexus 5
CUSTOM_DATA=
STACK_TRACE=java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.evernews.evernews.AlarmReceiver: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2732)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:207)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:191)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
at com.evernews.evernews.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:48)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2725)
... 8 more
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:207)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:191)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
at com.evernews.evernews.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:48)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2725)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

One more version :

```
USER_COMMENT=null
ANDROID_VERSION=5.0.2
APP_VERSION_NAME=0.0337
BRAND=htc
PHONE_MODEL=HTC Desire 816 dual sim
CUSTOM_DATA=
STACK_TRACE=android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:235)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:219)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:834)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:737)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:712)
at com.evernews.evernews.Main.parseResultsRefresh(Main.java:1194)
at com.evernews.evernews.Main$GetNewsTaskRestart.onPostExecute(Main.java:827)
at com.evernews.evernews.Main$GetNewsTaskRestart.onPostExecute(Main.java:778)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Comment: How about adding the relevant code parts. That are the lines the error talks about your own code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135049/android-database-sqlite-sqlitecantopendatabaseexception-unknown-error-code-14