# Cannot open Database file

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an application that creates a database file at '/storage/emulated/0/databases/mydb.db' and there are files within this DB.
I have another application which tries to open this database. But I get error code 14. Could not open database when trying to oprn the table in this db.

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
public String TABLE_NAME;
// Database Information
static final String DB_NAME = "mydb.DB";
public static final String FILE_DIR = "databases";
private String DB_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + File.separator + FILE_DIR + File.separator + DB_NAME;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name) {
    super(context, name, null, 1);
    TABLE_NAME = name;
}

public void openDatabase() throws SQLiteException {
    String DBPath = DB_PATH + "/" +TABLE_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DBPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

I get an error at `myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DBPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);`

Comment: Did you check the permissions of the created file? Two different apps are always two different Linux users.

Comment: I am not using a rooted phone. so default permissions.

Comment: You can share your database by either making a ContentProvider or by placing the database in a folder which is accessible from both the apps (and potentially to all your installed apps).

Comment: @Rotwang yes, so I have created the database in external storage, to make it accessible from all other apps. But it still gives error.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/` is not present on every device at this exact location. Instead of harcoding your path, you should get the path to the external storage by using the proper `Environment` methods

Comment: I have created it at:  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + File.separator + FILE_DIR + File.separator + DB_NAME;
and I am trying to access it from:  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + File.separator + FILE_DIR + File.separator + DB_NAME;

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to note is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` has been deprecated in API 29:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory()

> This method was deprecated in API level 29.
>
> To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated. **When an app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.Q, the path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps**. Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external storage by migrating to alternatives such as Context#getExternalFilesDir(String), MediaStore, or Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Permission**

Your app needs file read permission. Above Android 6.0, you need to request runtime permission.

See this: [android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034511/android-database-sqlite-sqlitecantopendatabaseexception-unknown-error-code-14)

**2. Wrong path**

It seems that the path

> /storage/emulated/0/databases/mydb.db

is not same as path below.

> Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
>           + File.separator + FILE_DIR + File.separator + DB_NAME

So, before open database file, compare two paths to check it is same.

```
if (DB_PATH.compareTo("/storage/emulated/0/databases/mydb.db")){
    // Do something
}
```

And check the to find out it really exists.

```
File file = new File(myPath);    
if (file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
    // Do something
}
```

Details: [android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135049/android-database-sqlite-sqlitecantopendatabaseexception-unknown-error-code-14)